# Getting data from function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am having some trouble getting the logged in status from the below function.
I can set the loggedIn status with `currentUser.setProfile(username, token)`, which works.

But when i then try to get the `isLoggedIn` afterwards, i can't seem to get it.

`console.log(currentUser)` return the 2 functions, `setProfile` and `getProfile`. But `getProfile` is just an empty function.
I have tried `currentUser.getProfile.isLoggedIn` among others, but they all just return undefined.

What am i doing wrong?

Function:

```
(function () {
    "use strict";

    angular
        .module("myApp")
        .factory("currentUser",
                  currentUser)

    function currentUser() {
        var profile = {
            isLoggedIn: false,
            username: "",
            token: ""
        };

        var setProfile = function (username, token) {
            profile.username = username;
            profile.token = token;
            profile.isLoggedIn = true;
        };

        var getProfile = function () {
            return profile;
        }

        return {
            setProfile: setProfile,
            getProfile: getProfile
        }
    }
})();
```

Comment: Try `currentUser.getProfile().isLoggedIn`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `getProfile` is a function, you should call it like

```
currentUser.getProfile().isLoggedIn
```